# Mongoose prevent duplicate id numbers based on document.count()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My documents all have sequential numbers, saved as a String as an ID (it's padded with 0s). When creating a new record, I first do a request for Comment.count(). Using the number returned from that, I generate the ID string. I then create an object, and save it as a new document.

```
    var commentNumber = (result[1] + 1).toString().padStart(4, '0');

    var newComment = this({
        html: processedHtml,
        number: commentNumber
    });

    newComment.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err) return callback(err);

        return callback(null, result);

    });
```

The problem is, if two comments are submitted at the same time, they will get the same ID (this happens if I make 2 requests on submission instead of 1, they will both have the same ID).

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option would be to create a unique index on `number` so that one of the requests fails.

Another would be to store the current number count elsewhere. If you wanted to use mongo, you could have a doc with `commentCount` in a different collection & do a `findAndUpdate` with `$inc` and use the returned value. This still leads to a weird race condition where a user might only see comments `1` and `3` when comment `2` takes longer to create than comment `3`.

I think the approach of storing the comment number on the document is fundamentally flawed: it creates weird race conditions, strange error handling, and complex deletes. If possible, it's better to calculate the number of comments on the way out.

As far as ordering goes, mongo _ids encode date-time information at the start of the _id, so you can use the _id to sort documents.

Comment: So I could store the count in memory / use a datastore, meaning I increment it and use the incremented number immediately, but then what if something fails after that? I imagine I could decrement it on failure, but if another comment went through before it failed, it would already have the next number in the sequence, and decrementing would mean the next number would be the same as the comment that went through. I could just not decrement it and accept the gap in numbers any time there's an error. Is that normal?

Comment: This is exactly why this is a really hard problem! If you can, it's best to avoid solving it. You could do something like adding a "fence" to the external data-store to lock use of the value, but even that can have tons of problems